# What is a primitive root?

Tags: definition, primitive-roots

So I'm trying to learn about RSA and have come across various subtopics, including the discrete logarithm problem.

This mentions primitive roots, which I do not understand.

Essentially all I want is an answer in simple terms of what a primitive root actually is.

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n ? If not please do so and ask a more specifc question.

Comment: I have read that, but essentially what I want to know is, can a primitive root be defined in a simpler, easier to understand way? For my level of mathematics, some of the more formal definitions can be hard to understand sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sometimes find it helpful to think of primitive roots as akin to logarithms...that is, a way to change multiplication into addition.  For example, let's consider powers of $3$ mod$(17)$.  They are: $$\{3,9,10,13,5,15,11,16,14,8,7,4,12,2,6,1\}$$

We note there are $16$ distinct values, so $3$ is indeed a primitive root mod$(17)$.  We now ask, for each residue class $i$, what power of $3$ gives $i$ mod$(17)$?  By inspection these "logarithms" are:

$$\{16, 14, 1, 12, 5, 15, 11, 10, 2,3, 7, 13, 4,9,6,8\}$$

That is to say, $$3^{16}=1,\;\;3^{14}=2,\;\; 3^1=3,\;\;...$$

Now say you want to multiply $8$ by $13$ mod$(17)$.  We read off that $8=3^{10}$ and $13=3^4$  so $8*13=3^{14}=2$.

In this way, if you have a primitive root and you have a look up table for the "logarithms" then you can always reduce multiplication to addition.  Of course, it isn't all that easy to find primitive roots.

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful to me. Now my understanding of residue classes is also limited, but would I be correct to say that for an integer n, there are n-1 residue classes?

Comment: Be careful.  Ordinarily one restricts to residues which are coprime to the modulus.  If $n=p$ is prime then there are $p-1$ residues.  For general $n$ you get $\varphi(n)$, Euler's phi-function.  Easy to read about that online.  There are primitive roots for composite moduli, but of course you only get the coprime residues.

Comment: So for example, with n=10, you would have 4 residue sets, as phi(10) is 4, but with n=7, you would have 6 residue sets?

Comment: Your math is correct, but to avoid ambiguity I would always spell out what I meant.  That is, I would say something like "there are exactly 4 residue classes prime to $10$ mod$(10)$"  or I'd use algebraic notation and write $$\#\left(\frac {\mathbb Z}{10\mathbb Z}\right)^*=4$$  People, including myself, use the word "residue" somewhat casually, trusting that context will make it clear if you want to include $0$, say.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Let $n>1$ be a natural number.

Let $S$ be the set of numbers coprime to $n$. A number $m$ is called a primitive
root in $\mathbb Z_n$, if the Set $\{m,m^2,m^3,...,m^{\phi(n)}\}$ modulo $n$ contains
every element of $S$.

$\phi(n)$ is the Euler-Phi-Function : The number of $m's$ with $gcd(m,n)=1$

Example : $n=10$

Numbers coprime to $10$ : $\{1,3,7,9\}$

The elements $3,3^2,3^3,3^4$ are congruent $3,9,7,1$ modulo $10$, so all the
numbers occur. Hence, $3$ is a primitve root in $\mathbb Z_{10}$

Comment: Would you mean " if the Set {m,m2,m3,...,mϕ(n)} modulo n contains  every element of S." or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean (See the example)

Comment: Yes I thought that from the example, was just making sure! Thanks for that, on a bit of a side note, can I ask what is the point in finding a primitive root? How are they used?

Comment: Primitive roots are generators of the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$, which is useful in proofs. Moreover primitive roots are difficult to compute in some groups, and cryptography takes advantage of this difficulty